# Rich suggestion box trims extra spaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am calling a suggestionBox for an inputText element. Before it sends the input string to the backend method, its trimming the spaces after the end. 
Even if i enter           'Rudy  '
it will just send         'Rudy'

How do we stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the suggestionBox is trimming the input? I've tested it in my environment and the whole text including the spaces at the beginning and and is transferred to the backend and stored in the variables.
Although, if I output the entered text somewhere on the webpage again, the spaces get trimmed during the output-rendering.

Edit: you are right - now I can reproduce your problem